# Is there more neat design for requesting static fields in class successors?

Tags: reflection, static, field, haxe

I'm implementing network controller that sends requests to the server with integer command type id and binary serialized block of other command data. Prototype of all commands looks like:

```
class NetCommand {

    public static var typeId; // type must be set in successors!

    function new() {
    }

    public function typeGet():Int {
        return Reflect.field(Type.getClass(this), "typeId");
    }

}
```

All this mess in typeGet() function done just for access to the static variables with type ids of all successors. I can't simply write

```
return typeId;
```

because statics are not inheritable and this method will return 0 as a value of prototype's variable. Is there any neat solution? Is my solution cross-platform?

**Update:**

All command classes must be registered in controller class like this:

```
public function bindResponse(aClass:Class<NetCommand>) {
    var typeId = Reflect.field(aClass, "typeId");
    mBindResponse.set(typeId, aClass);
}
```

and then when new command arrives its data passes to the method that find necessary class by command id, creates instance of desired class and passes other data to it:

```
function onResponse(aTypeId:Int, aData:Dynamic) {
    var cmdClass:Class<NetCommand> = mBindResponse.get(aTypeId);
    var command:NetCommand = Type.createInstance(cmdClass, []);
    command.response(aData); // this must be overriden in successor classes
}
```

Method `typeGet()` is used only for targeting outgoing **instances** and error handling with default behaviour of error command class without creating a heap of classes that differs only by `typeId` constant. So this method suppreses implementation of the real command id and may be overriden for example.

Comment: Instead of `IntMap<Class<NetCommand>>` you could do `StringMap<Class<NetCommand>>` and use the class name as the typeId... Or you could use metadata like: `@typeID(1) class MeNetCommand {}`, possibly even with a macro to complain if you forget to add the metadata.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply make `typeId` an instance member (not `static`) ?

Comment: Because I'd like to get these `typeId` from classes without instantiating of objects. I register outgouing and incoming commands only by their types and then place them in `IntMap<Class<NetCommand>>`.

Comment: @meps can you post some code showing how are you planning to use this?

Comment: I have updated question. Now I suppose that my solution is not so ugly as I think at first...